# How to root a Lenovo Tab M8 FHD (TB_8705F)

Tags: rooting, lenovo

I have tried to root my tablet using the one click options but wasn't successful.

Does anyone know of a way to root it?

Thank You,

Comment: try mtk-su bootless root

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for your suggestion. I will probably try this on another device I have but for the Lenovo tab M8 see my answer  since I found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that I found after a lot of research and trial and error.

**Disclaimer I don't take any responsibility for your device follow this at your own risk!**

1. **Warning This step will factory reset device (delete all your data)** Unlock your bootloader.

   - Turn on OEM unlocking and USB Debugging in developer settings.
   - On Pc do fastboot flashing unlock. For more info on unlocking please see [here.](https://www.howtogeek.com/239798/how-to-unlock-your-android-phones-bootloader-the-official-way/)
2. Get the firmware for your device using "Rescue and Smart Assistant"
   form Lenovo's website. You will need to log in with your Lenovo ID
   to be able to
3. Install Magisk Manager on your device.
4. Get the boot.img from the firmware and copy it onto your device.
5. In Magisk Manager click on `Install` and select `Select and Patch File` then select the boot.img you copied.
6. Copy the patched image back to the PC.
7. Flash the patched image to the boot partition with fastboot.

All Done!

Comment: please note the link is not common method for Lenovo bootloader unlock, there are several devices where one 
need unlock code https://www.hardreset.info/devices/lenovo/lenovo-tb3-710f-tab3-7-essential/faq/faq/bootloader-moto-unlock-lenovo-motorola-root

Comment: I updated the link to a better tutorial. Basically its unlocked the same like most devices any online search will provide the directions.